# Javascript or other language to move desktop files

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

i want to be able to move pictures from desktop to desktop folder "pictures"
can it be done via JS? if not maybe Ajax, PHP, HTML?

any way it's possible?

edit: I do not want to do it on my server on web users, so I understand it cannot be done how about if they allow it (Java?)

Comment: You've chosen some very strange candidate languages. Are you trying to do this from a web application? Tell us more about your use case, and maybe we can help you.

Comment: You can use JavaScript or PHP if you run it on the client. But of course not if the JavaScript runs in the browser and/or the PHP at some server. You can also use Python, bash, Perl, etc. HTML is not really a programming language. It is a markup language.  I think you need to provide more information to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done using any web technology.

EDIT: Not in a meaningfully useful way. Like the other answers have pointed out, you can use ActiveX objects with IE or move files on a server using PHP. But this is not generalizable.

Comment: Jog How about if you ask the user to allow it for example Java?

Comment: You need signed applets for accessing the filesystem using Java.

Comment: Does that include Flash vulnerability exploits? Those practically constitute a "web technology"...

Answer (score 0):

If your executing the file on the local machine you could create a batch script, however this can't be done from the web.

Comment: Yeah im looking to do it from the web to visitors

Answer (score 0):

you could use JS with ActiveX akl JScript.  VBScript, hell you can use PHP to move files around.  I would just use a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can with JS if you use ActiveX (only on IE), and with php if the php server is the computer where you want to move files.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do with PHP so long as you are moving files on the server. This can be triggered from a client, but PHP can not move files on a client.

If the server and client are the same machine, then a batch script is probably more appropriate